# И волки, и лисы, и тигры(,) и др

Tags: запятые

Понятно, что здесь не надо запятой?

> И волки, и лисы, и тигры и т. д.

А здесь-таки?

> И волки, и лисы, и тигры(,) и др.

Comment: Ответ дополнен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Др.* — сокращение от *другие*. Следовательно, по [«Розенталю», пункт 10](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101), запятая нужна:

***И волки, и лисы, и тигры, и др***.

Так же, как и:

***И волки, и лисы, и тигры, и другие***.

По тому же пункту можно сказать, что в первом, действительно, не нужна запятая:

***И волки, и лисы, и тигры и т. д***.